# Nokogiri XML query

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

```
<XML>
  <EVENT>
    <SHOPS>
      <SHOP shopid="0001" name="London" city="LONDON"/>
    </SHOPS>
    <HISTORY>
      <WIN shopid="0001" amount="2000" time="2015-03-28 19:09:23"/>
    </HISTORY>
  </EVENT>
</XML>
```

How would you write this Nokogiri query in a xml file ?

1. iterate through the xml file and find the node with attribute amount > 900
2. get the attribute shopid of this node
3. retrieve the name and city of the shopid with amount > 900

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of 'the long way', using lots of Ruby and walking around the document:

```ruby
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri.XML( File.read('my.xml') )

wins = doc.search('WIN')
wins_with_amount = wins.select{ |win| win['amount'] }
first_big = wins_with_amount.find{ |win| win['amount'].to_i > 900 }
shop_id   = first_big['shopid']
shop      = doc.search('SHOP').find{ |shop| shop['shopid']==shop_id }
puts shop['name'], shop['city']
```

The fast way, using just XPath:

```ruby
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri.XML( File.read('my.xml') )

shop = doc.at('//SHOP[@shopid=//WIN[@amount>900]/@shopid]')
puts shop['name'], shop['city']
```

Explaining that XPath query:

- `//SHOP` - Find all `SHOP` elements

  - `[@shopid=...]` ... whose `shopid` attribute matches this criteria
  - `//WIN` - Find all `WIN` elements

    - `[@amount>900]` ...that have an `amount` attribute whose value is greater than `900`

      - `/@shopid` ... find the `shopid` attribute of these WIN elements.